# How to sum result in each Table and Round from RoundResult in HomePayerResult

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of players each player have Array of player result.
I try to sum all result for a specific round and table.

```
HomePlayerResults.RoundResult.Select(x => x.Table == 1 && x.Round == 1).Result;
```

tryed:

```
var H1 = matchResult.HomePlayerResults.SelectMany(x => x.RoundResults.GroupBy(res => res.Table)).ToList();
```

But then i´ll sum res.Result for each round

Comment: This question is completely unclear. Please add more details so that a proper answer can be given

Answer (score 2):

Without more details this is a very hard question to answer and you really need to provide much more context for the issue at hand, but I'll answer it based upon what was provided.

**What you actually asked:**

For this statement: `I have a list of players each player have Array of player result. I try to sum all result for a specific round and table`

Okay, given these classes:

```
public class Result 
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
}
public class Player
{
    public IEnumerable<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

You'd do this to sum all the results of all the players:

```
var players = new List<Player>();
var results = players.Sum(x => x.Sum(y => y.Val));
```

**What it looks like your intentions are from your provided code**

If I'm understanding your wording right it sounds like you are trying to sum the results *from a specific 'round'*, after which you then show this:

```
HomePlayerResults.RoundResult.Select(x => x.Table == 1 && x.Round == 1).Result;
```

This looks like you are trying to use `Select` as a `Where` clause, which is incorrect.  The above will return a collection of 'true' or 'false' *booleans* and then compile time fail because `Result` does not exist on a boolean.  I think THIS is what you are trying to do:

```
HomePlayerResults.RoundResult.Where(x => x.Table == 1 && x.Round == 1).Sum(x => x.Result);
```

I could be way off base, but without clarifying your question better or adding more details this is about as much as we can do to help.

Comment: You should ask for further details rather than going all the way of assuming stuff. Specially when the given code does not even compile (an IQueryable<T> does not have a Result property). Nicely done, though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I agree on asking for further details, however the code that does not compile is his which I specifically note thereafter.  Then I followed up with code that would compile if the unknown type returned from his 'HomePlayerResults.RoundResult' object (whatever that is) has a `Result` property.  Given the proposed question, I offered an answer that corrected what the invalid code appeared to be attempting.

Comment: Not saying you did anything wrong, quite the opposite, you did too much. but I'd rather discourage the user of thinking that by writing 2 words they will get their task done by other. They should at least ask a question where we don't have to guess what they meant or need

Answer (score 0):

Ok Sorry i copy the Class MatchResult: Then i explain what result i want futher down.

```
public class MatchResults
{
    public string MatchAdmin { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public int allotHome { get; set; }
    public int allotAway { get; set; }
    public bool StrikeOut { get; set; }
    public int StrikeOutNbrOfRounds { get; set; }
    public int homeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int awayTeamId { get; set; }
    public int MatchId { get; set; }
    public bool Hcp { get; set; }
    public bool HcpBrutto { get; set; }
    public bool Allot { get; set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; }
    public int Lanes { get; set; }
    public string SchemeId { get; set; }
    public List<PlayerResult> HomePlayerResults { get; set; }
    public List<PlayerResult> AwayPlayerResults { get; set; }
    public List<SquadResult> HomeSquadResults { get; set; }
    public List<SquadResult> AwaySquadResults { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerResult
{
    public string LicNbr { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string PlayerShortName { get; set; }
    public string NameAndLicNbr { get; set; }
    public int ShirtNo { get; set; }
    public int Hcp { get; set; }
    public List<RoundResult> RoundResults { get; set; }
}

public class RoundResult
{
    public int Round { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public int Table { get; set; }
    public int Squad { get; set; }
    public int RoundNbr { get; set; }
}
```

So when this MatchResult Class from ServiceReference, i got one MatchResult and in this i have results from HomeTeam and AwayTeam. EatchTeam has PlayerResult witch is 8 players and one substitute So the list is 0 - 8. 
Each PlayerResult has RoundResult[ 0 - 4] In there ic want to list for Each Round Each Table the pair of Players Result and Calc agains AwayTeam Pair Of player at same Table same Round who wins the minimatch. 
From that i need to show the Winner Point.

There is an issue. From Round[1] There can be an player [0-7] with no result, si the substitute and that player shall swap placee. For example player [3] round 2 dont play that round, so substitute get [3] and player[3] get player[8] position in List of HomPlayerResult.

Hope you understand..
Best Regards
Gert